# .js script not responding

Tags: javascript, html, css, coda

New to all of this and trying to get my .js script to work in Coda2. If anyone has any idea of why the .js script file is not responding, that would be great!

Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Magic</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
    <script type= 'text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type= 'text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>
</body>
```

In the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    $('div').fadeTo('fast',1);
});
$('div').mouseleave(function(){
    $('div').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
});
```

});

Please find the image here of my code:

http://postimg.org/image/qis0sitd1/

Comment: Please paste the code here as text.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Button Magic</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type= 'text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
 </body>
</html>

Comment: To the question, please.

Comment: you havent included the Jquery lib,so the `$(document).ready.....` would not work

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').slideDown('slow');
});

Comment: It usually helps to look at the browser error console and read any error messages that might appear there.

Comment: To test whether the .js file is linked, you can try adding an `alert("test");`. If it doesn't work, make sure the `.js` file is in the root location.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Edit the question and add your code to question

Comment: How do you include the Jquery lib? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Same as you have with your file. I've updated my answer to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the jQuery library. You can use the [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Magic</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
        <script type= 'text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type= 'text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed the head to match what you advised. Is there anything else that I need to change to make it respond? Still no function when I .mouseenter

Comment: Do you have this on a local server? Or are you running it using the `file:` protocol?

Comment: Its on my local computer. Do I have to put it up on the server to make it work?

Comment: You do with that URL structure. For testing locally, append `http:` to the beginning of the Google link. I've updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: YOU are a LEGEND! Got it to work. I have been trying for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added a script tag to include jQuery.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: indeed + is the js file located in the same directory as the html file ?

Comment: I did wonder, but from the screenshot, is seemed as if it was from looking at the breadcrumbs.

Comment: Definitely in the same directory as the html file and css file.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the Jquery lib, please include one.

eg: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js